# sort data with special chars

Tags: mysql, sql

In a column I have this kind of varchars.

```
Home External +1 PD  
Home +24 PD  
Home +1 PD  
Home Set 1 PD  
Home External +12 PD   
Home 1 PD  
Home External +2 PD  
Home Set +1 PD  
Home External +24 PD  
Home Set PD
```

I'm trying to sort them out in this way:
(alphabetical and numerical order)

```
Home 1 PD  
Home +1 PD  
Home +24 PD  
Home External +1 PD  
Home External +2 PD  
Home External +12 PD   
Home External +24 PD  
Home Set PD  
Home Set 1 PD  
Home Set +1 PD
```

my problem is that I can have multiple names with different names length, in this case is Home but I also have other.
Tried to query with CAST, ABS but I can't get it out as I would.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems your table design wasn't normalized sufficiently - if you had separate columns for the various components this would be a very simple query, but as it is now its going to be a really messy job :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the column value to extract string and number parts.

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) function passing -1 and -2 to get indexes of last 2 space chars.

SUbstring between last and previous last space is number part, Substring from the value start to the second last space is text part.

So you should add
ORDER BY TEXT_PART_CALCULATED, NUMBER_PART_CALCULATED